# How do I have YAHOO.util.KeyListener disabled when an input element is focused?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, yui, shortcut, keylistener

I have a MenuBar setup with [YUI's MenuBar](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/menu/) widget, and I have a `YAHOO.util.KeyListener` attached to *document* to get quick keyboard access to the menus and sub-menu items (e.g. 's' to open the Setup menu).  The problem is that the *keylistener* will still fire when a user is in an input element.  For example, a user might be typing *soup* into a text field, and the 's' character will cause the Setup menu to pop open.

One solution would be to disable the *keylistener* when focus is on an input element, and enable it on blur.  How would I go about doing this?  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commend you for trying to provide keyboard shortcuts, but be aware that this will be a bit of a pain to implement cross-platform. If it's feasible, I strongly recommend using [access keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.11.2) on `<a>` tags.

If you're still going, I guess `accesskey` won't work for you. I'll assume you've read [the relevant YUI tutorial](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/container/keylistener.html).

If `blur` and `focus` are really the right way to go, I'd use something like

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(init);
function init() {
    // set up the keyboard listeners

    setUpExceptionsToKeyboardShortcuts();
}

function disableShortcuts() {
    // Do what you've got to do
}

function enableShortcuts() {
    // Do what you've got to do
}

function setUpExceptionsToKeyboardShortcuts() {
    var focusable = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    focusable = focusable.concat(document.getElementsByTagName('select'));
    focusable = focusable.concat(document.getElementsByTagName('textarea'));
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(focusable, 'focus', disableShortcuts);
    YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(focusable, 'blur', ensableShortcuts);
}
```

Comment: The reference to access keys was great, I completely forgot about them.  Unfortunately, they won't be good enough for this situation.